# Error in Visual Studio Code std_lib_facilities.h C++

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, visual-studio-code

I'm studying C++ with this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321992784) which has this header file. When I try to run a simple "Hello, world!" program the compiler complains and give me this output. I'm using latest macOS. Could somebody please help me?

```
[Running] cd "/Users/Ramsan/Praxis/" && g++ yup.cpp -o yup && "/Users/Ramsan/Praxis/"yup
In file included from yup.cpp:1:
/Users/Ramsan/std_lib_facilities.h:71:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
                          ^
/Users/Ramsan/std_lib_facilities.h:101:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        using size_type = std::string::size_type;
                          ^
/Users/Ramsan/std_lib_facilities.h:218:73: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
inline int randint(int min, int max) { return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(get_rand()); }
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/Ramsan/std_lib_facilities.h:227:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;
                   ^
/Users/Ramsan/std_lib_facilities.h:230:18: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using Iterator = typename C::iterator;
                 ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.795 seconds
```

Comment: The compiler is out-of-date or configured to use an older (1998 or 2003) revision of the C++ Standard version.  You will have to adjust one of the JSON config files to instruct the compiler to use at least the C++11 revision. Hopefully someone who is more familiar with VS Code will be along shortly to point you at a duplicate question.

Comment: You need to edit `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`. The VSCode documentation is here and it shows you how to enable c++17: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: I've followed that documentation many times, but I get same result. How do you update clang anyway? Isn't it automatically update when you update Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the vscode tutorial on setting up clang for macOS C++ development, you will hit into a problem with setting up a default build task.

The tutorial guides you to generate a tasks.json and then gets you to replace the contents with its own example. This initial task compiles with C++17.

It then guides you to generate a launch.json for debugging. What happens at this point is the debugger task generates its own task inside tasks.json and set it to default.

This new default tasks lacks args to compile with C++11/14/17, std_lib_facilities.h requires C++11. When vscode runs the build it uses the wrong task.